# Bootstrap carousel not initializing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

in the class carouse-inner dynamic adding

```
<div class = "active item"><img ..></div>
<div class = "item"><img ..></div>
<div class = "item"><img..</div>
```

and call

```
$('.carousel').carousel();
```

In inspect element, carousel html is correct, but slide on arrows click not working.
I think bootstrap carousel not init.

Comment: maybe there's something wrong with your bootstrap.js path or with your jquery path.

Comment: I need to use bootstrap 2, not 3.

Comment: i updated the answer. please try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace your current bootstrap and jquery `<script>` with this. Place this before the `</body>`

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: not work. appear this error  Object [object Object] has no method 'swiper'

Comment: you can view it here   http://lacremedeparis.ru/ru/site/articles       in bottom of each articles there are pictures clicking at one pic appeard modal inside it will work caorusel slider that carousel doesnt work and appeard error

Comment: I opened the link. It's working fine here. Or maybe you already fixed it?

Comment: Works here too, which browser do you use?

Comment: @Getz I'm using Chrome Version 32.0.1700.107 m.

Comment: I asked user3283209 ;)

Comment: I use jquery fancybox, not bootstrap carousel & it work fine. Thank you very much.